# u-boot - control characters support disabled

Tags: u-boot

To stop autoboot we have 2 ifdef (CONFIG_AUTOBOOT_STOP_ [STR2 || STR1] ). Which is very easy and straightforward to implement. Halting a boot with single “Keystroke” or with a pharase is having its own advantages to the user. But, why contole key support is ignored say like [ctrl + anykey ] combination. Especially, BIOS vendors prefer at least simultaneous pressing of 2 or more keys to halt the boot. Any specific reasons to avoid this. Other than simplicity is there any specific reason to stick on this.

Comment: Bios vendors prefer F1 key. Especially when the keyboard in NOT found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The <kbd>**CTRL**</kbd> key is a modifier. And <kbd>**CTRL**</kbd>+<kbd>**KEY**</kbd> combos register as normal <kbd>**KEY**</kbd> press event with additional flags set to indicate the status of modifier keys. Read about **modifiers** in keyboard drivers in the [Linux kernel keyboard driver documentation](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/pdf/Keyboard-and-Console-HOWTO.pdf).

Also check this excellent **[article on how keyboards work](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/1080)**.

Handling all the modifiers requires additional complexity in the code. Bootloaders run in a severely constrained environment. Especially on embedded systems(which u-boot is meant for), it is very common to expect the entire u-boot to load and run within 64/128K of RAM (the binary + stack).

Considering the fact that we have >50 unique keys on our keyboards to bang before we require using modifiers, software support for them is usually not implemented in u-boot.